# using .htaccess to serve index.html or index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use .htaccess file to return homepage (index.html) if direct access to the web site (no parameters), and index.php/subdirectories/.... if other links

example :

my_site.com        displaying index.html

my_site.com/dir1/dir2/   must redirect to index.php with parameter dir1/dir2..

please help creating this .htaccess file

i have in existing file this :

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)(.html|.htm)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]

i want to do exception to index.html file which serve when entering site

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# to redirect my.site.com to my.site.com/index.html
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R,L]

# to redirect /dir1/dir2 to index.php?url=dir1/dir2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^url=
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?url=$1/$2 [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works in one server, but in another it does not work

Comment: mod_rewrite is well installed and working fine in the two servers, I can't verify apache in the first server (which .htaccess working fine) because it is not dedicated server, but it has works fine on. i need just to correct the second .htaccess (of dedicated server) to let executing index.html if (mysite.com or mysite.com/index.html), and executing index.php to all other files and directories (mysite.com/page1.html mysite.com/all_directories/../../,    mysite.com/all_directories/index.html .....), please help

Comment: yes RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R,L]           does not works in the 2nd computer, it give content from index.php

Comment: @aubhava, .htaccess works on the second server, but it does not serve index.html file by default in my_site.com it execute index.php

Comment: Thank you, yes it was the order in apache config, but after correction and restarting apache, it redirect my_site.com to my_site.com/index.htmlindex.php and displays homepage, and my_site.com/index.html displays the real content of index.html file. this is the content of my .htaccess : `RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/index.html$ index.html [C]

RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]

`

Comment: after commenting them, my_site.com try to show **index.htmlindex.php** and serve index.php content,

Answer (score 0):

If u have only html you can use like that also .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

    RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R,L]

</IfModule>
```